# OpenCV: Does the C++ API and the C API differ in functionality or speed?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have seen that most of the people here ask questions about the C++ version - for example data types such as `cv::Mat` and the `cv::` namespace in general, while I use the C version myself using `IplImage` and the C functions.

Is there any significant functionality and speed difference between these two APIs?

Comment: There is no difference in speed and functionality. Its just a matter of choice. An exception is the GPU accelerated functions which are available only in the C++ interface, inside the namespace `cv::gpu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any active C development in OpenCV so any new features introduced to the library (such as the extensive machine learning module) will be in C++. Of course, you can always convert your C data structures to their C++ equivalents and continue to work with those but I find the C++ Mat class much more flexible and easy to use than CvMat and IplImage.